# Docker exec with -ef flag

Tags: docker

What `docker exec` does with `-ef` flag ? I've tried to find it in the docs
but no luck.

this topic isn't helpful [docker exec or docker container exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898193/docker-exec-or-docker-container-exec)

Comment: Can you please include a complete, real command using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `docker exec` does not have the `-f` option, `f` here is an argument for `-e` (`--env`), which, in turn, usually accepts a list of `KEY=VALUE` pairs - the environment variables to be set/modified for the `exec`'d process.

The intersting point is that [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) neither describes the exact format of the `--env` option arguments, nor explains, what would happen if the argument is not in usual `KEY=VALUE` form.

Considering that `-ef` is a valid argument, it would be logical to assume that it treats `f` as a name of an environment variable. Further, as we do not supply the value (no `=` after the name), it would be rational to assume that the variable would be either unchanged, or unset. We may check this empirically. Create the container with additional environment variable set:

```
$ docker run -d -e TESTVAR=testval --name test alpine sleep 1000
```

Check the actual environment of the container:

```
$ docker exec test env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=27979b7f0ceb
TESTVAR=testval
HOME=/root
```

Then try to run `exec` with `-e TESTVAR`:

```
$ docker exec -e TESTVAR test env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=27979b7f0ceb
HOME=/root
```

Looks like the variable is unset. But what if `TESTVAR` is currently set in our shell?

```
$ export TESTVAR=12345
$ docker exec -e TESTVAR test env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=3fa7190750aa
TESTVAR=12345
HOME=/root
```

So, it seems that passing the variable name without the value sets this variable for the `exec`'d process to the value, currently set for the calling process (actually, it turns out that this behavior is described in the documentation for [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file), and `docker exec` just behaves the same way, though undocumented).

Back to the original question, the answer is: `docker exec -ef` sets the environment variable `f` for the `exec`'d process to the value of `f` variable in the current shell, if this variable is set, or unsets it for the `exec`'d process, if the variable is not currently set.

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer as I haven't found more satisfying answer to this. If `f` is treated here as an environmental variable then it should've been typed as `-E f` and not `-ef`. One dash flags are usually followed by upper case letter, space, and then the variable or value. Two dashes are usually followed by more verbose flag such as this `--port` and then variable or value hence I got confused when seeing `-ef`. Docker apparently uses different flagging syntax.

Comment: Yeah I just found it in the docs. In docker `--env` is equivalent to `-e`.