# Difference between docker exec and docker container exec

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-exec

What is the difference between "docker exec" and "docker container exec"?
The same for the difference between "docker commit" and "docker container commit"?

I researched a lot but couldn't find any.
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Here you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898193/docker-exec-or-docker-container-exec

Comment: They’re the same, but neither should be in your core workstream (especially not `docker commit`).